# Convert complex number to trigonometric form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I don't know how to change complex number $z=5+7i$ to trigonometric form

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice that:
>
> $$z=\Re[z]+\Im[z]i=|z|e^{\arg(z)i}=|z|\cos(\arg(z))+|z|\sin(\arg(z))i$$
>
> Where $|z|$ is the absolute value of $z$ and $\arg(z)$ is the argument of $z$.

Now, when we've $z=5+7i$:

$$z=|5+7i|e^{\arg(5+7i)i}=\sqrt{5^2+7^2}e^{\arctan\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)i}=\sqrt{74}e^{\arctan\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)i}=$$
$$\sqrt{74}\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)\right)+\sqrt{74}\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac{7}{5}\right)\right)i=5+7i$$

Comment: Thank you very much guy You made my day.

Comment: @user343864 Hahaha, you're welcome. I'm glad that I could help!